# Sending PHP / Special Characters through HTTP Request Body (IIS)

Tags: c#, api, iis

I am working on a xamarin app in which I do not completely control the data that is being sent over to me, as the data is stored externally. If I'm honest, the guy who created their API doesn't understand how web requests work, and is constantly sending stray PHP, SQL and HTML along with his responses to API calls.

For example, sometimes on the 'deleteReport' function, on failure he will send the whole PHP page with inline SQL scripts included, so all I really use to identify success of that will be the status code. Although this is really awful to work with, it has a small circle of users in an internal commercial application and so I have no choice but to deal with it.

Due to the above, I am logging EVERYTHING by sending web requests over to a function on the CMS, which is a C# app running on IIS.

This works about 99% of the time, however I've found that when it fails, I am given a load of random PHP and SQL and so I get a 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client' error message, and the log doesn't hit the function.

I have tried setting requestPathInvalidCharacters="" with no luck.

**How do I send logs to my IIS application without them being rejected due to special characters (&, $ etc)? The data is in the request body, and not the URL.**

Thank you.

EDIT: Possible solution I am going to try out, encoding logs and decoding them on receipt.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <pages validateRequest="false" />  
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it still gives me the same error message unfortunately.